# How to index xml content in xml tag with Solr

Tags: xml, parsing, solr, indexing

I have database and table named PriceList.
When I put all colums in xml, I got this xml

```
`<xml>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">1</field>
    <field name="name">Data</field>
    <field name="metaname">
        <add>
          <doc>
             <field name="xid">a1</field>
             <field name="Xname">Meta</field>
          <doc>
         </add>
     </field>
   </doc>
   <doc>
    <field name="id">2</field>
    <field name="name">Data2</field>
    <field name="metaname">
          <add>
          <doc>
             <field name="xid">a2</field>
             <field name="Xname">Meta2</field>
          <doc>
         </add>
 </doc>
 <doc>
    <field name="id">3</field>
    <field name="name">Data2</field>
    <field name="metaname">
         <add>
            <doc>
             <field name="xid">a3</field>
             <field name="Xname">Meta3</field>
            <doc>
            </add>
        </doc>
     </xml>`
```

How to parse xml within field metaname that I get index all?

Comment: how do you want to index the internal tags? as separate docs?

Comment: I do not want different documents, but one index document with the above named fields

Answer (score 0):

Solr doesn't support a multilevel xml structure. It only supports a single level xml structure while indexing. Please refer https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What should I do? Maybe some other solution that would help?

Comment: You have to break down your data from multilevel to single level.